# Please help me to convert vb.NEt to C# ...... Addressof part is creating error for me

Tags: c#, vb.net

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class clsThread
    'This variable will hold the Thread Index that are passed from the main window, when we created it
    Private m_ThreadIndex As Integer

    'This is local thread variable. We will send the value of this variable to the parent form
    Private m_Counter As Integer = 0

    'We will need this variable to pass argument to the method of the main window
    Private m_Args(1) As Object

    'This will hold the ref to the main window,
    Private m_MainWindow As Form


    'Here we are going to call the method ReceiveThreadMessage() of the main form. 
    'So the declaration of the delete should be same as ReceiveThreadMessage()

    Private Delegate Sub NotifyMainWindow(ByVal ThreadIndex As Integer, ByVal Counter As Integer)
    'We need an object of this deletegate
    Private m_NotifyMainWindow As NotifyMainWindow

    Public Sub New(ByVal ThreadIndex As Integer, ByRef MainWindow As frmtest)
        m_ThreadIndex = ThreadIndex
        m_MainWindow = MainWindow

        'We need to point our delegate to the Method, which we want to call from this thread
        m_NotifyMainWindow = AddressOf MainWindow.ReceiveThreadMessage
    End Sub

    Public Sub StartThread()
        While True
            m_Counter = m_Counter + 1

            'we need to create this array such a way, that it should contains the no of elements, that we need
            'to pass as the arguments.
            'Here we will pass two arguments ThreadIndex and Counter, so we took the array with 2 elements.
            'Now we need to place the variable to the appropriate position of this array.
            'Like : Our First Argument is ThreadIndex, so we will put ThreadIndex into the first element and 
            'm_counter into the second element.
            'Basically you have to put the variables into the array with the same sequence that is there in the
            'argument list
            ReDim m_Args(1)
            m_Args(0) = m_ThreadIndex
            m_Args(1) = m_Counter

            'Call the notificaiton method on the main window by the delegate
            m_MainWindow.Invoke(m_NotifyMainWindow, m_Args)

            'wait for some time before continuing loop
            Thread.Sleep(1000)
        End While
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

- [C# Frequently Asked Questions](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/category/4156.aspx)
- [What do I use instead of
  addressof?](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/88475.aspx)

> To create delegate instances in C#,
>   you just specify the delegate type,
>   the method, and (if you want to create
>   a delegate targetting a different
>   instance or type from the current one)
>   the target. For instance, each of
>   these creates a ThreadStart delegate:
>
> ```
> ThreadStart x1 = new ThreadStart(SomeInstanceMethod);
> ThreadStart x2 = new ThreadStart(AnotherType.SomeStaticMethod);
> ThreadStart x3 = new ThreadStart(someVariable.SomeInstanceMethod);
> ```

Also keep this as a reference

[Complete Comparison for VB.NET and C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/vbnet_c__difference.aspx)

This converted code should help you

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class clsThread
{
    //This variable will hold the Thread Index that are passed from the main window, when we created it 
    private int m_ThreadIndex;

    //This is local thread variable. We will send the value of this variable to the parent form 
    private int m_Counter = 0;

    //We will need this variable to pass argument to the method of the main window 
    private object[] m_Args = new object[2];

    //This will hold the ref to the main window, 
    private Form m_MainWindow;


    //Here we are going to call the method ReceiveThreadMessage() of the main form. 
    //So the declaration of the delete should be same as ReceiveThreadMessage() 

    private delegate void NotifyMainWindow(int ThreadIndex, int Counter);
    //We need an object of this deletegate 
    private NotifyMainWindow m_NotifyMainWindow;

    public clsThread(int ThreadIndex, ref frmtest MainWindow)
    {
        m_ThreadIndex = ThreadIndex;
        m_MainWindow = MainWindow;

        //We need to point our delegate to the Method, which we want to call from this thread 
        m_NotifyMainWindow = MainWindow.ReceiveThreadMessage;
    }

    public void StartThread()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            m_Counter = m_Counter + 1;

            //we need to create this array such a way, that it should contains the no of elements, that we need 
            //to pass as the arguments. 
            //Here we will pass two arguments ThreadIndex and Counter, so we took the array with 2 elements. 
            //Now we need to place the variable to the appropriate position of this array. 
            //Like : Our First Argument is ThreadIndex, so we will put ThreadIndex into the first element and 
            //m_counter into the second element. 
            //Basically you have to put the variables into the array with the same sequence that is there in the 
            //argument list 
            int[] m_Args = new int[2];
            m_Args[0] = m_ThreadIndex;
            m_Args[1] = m_Counter;

            //Call the notificaiton method on the main window by the delegate 
            m_MainWindow.Invoke(m_NotifyMainWindow, m_Args);

            //wait for some time before continuing loop 
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#, method invocation *requires* a parenthesis, and by *omitting* the parenthesis you're basically passing the method itself.

And if you're on C# 3.5 and *the method _signature_ match the delegated being assigned to*, a delegate will be created automatically for you (with the help of type inferrence)

So, this line:

```
m_NotifyMainWindow = AddressOf MainWindow.ReceiveThreadMessage
```

When converted to C#, will simply becomes:

```
m_NotifyMainWindow = MainWindow.ReceiveThreadMessage;
```

Provided that `MainWindow` is either an instance and `ReceiveThreadMessage` is an instance method *or* it's a static class and `ReceiveThreadMessage` is a static method.

Basically, just *remove* the AddressOf operator, add a semicolon at the end of the line and you'll get the equivalent C# version.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the adressof part thats giving you problems you should be done in a sec. Just leave it out. c# allows you to assign a method to a delegate directly so

```
myDelegate = AddressOf obj.SomeMethod
```

in VB.NET becomes

```
myDelegate = obj.SomeMethod;
```

for more insights you could use tools as Reflector (RedGate Software) where you can decompile into both c# and VB.NET

Answer (score 0):

**Have a look at**

[TOP Code Converter](http://vb2cs.cf/)

**How to Use the Code Converter**
1-Switch conversion direction from C# to VB and from VB to C# by pressing
2-Paste or type code on the left. To convert entire documents select Upload files.
3- Hit orange button. Converted code will appear on the right, or there will be links to converted files to download.